# Free import contacts widget?

Tags: javascript, import, widget, contacts

I'm looking for a free open source import contacts widget, something like this http://tellafriend.socialtwist.com/.  A widget that I can customize it, and send the emails from another server, not my server.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Plaxo widget](http://www.plaxo.com/api/widget) out.  It's not open source, but is free.  It looks like it may be discontinued soon though.  Once it is deprecated, watch this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731547/need-to-find-replacement-to-plaxo-account-add-widget/7747729#7747729) for more options as people find them.