# Need to find replacement to Plaxo account add widget

Tags: javascript, widget, contacts, add-on

Plaxo is retiring their Contact widget, and I need to find a preferably free replacement ASAP to include in my site thats currently being developed.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated since its seemingly difficult to find on google.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plaxo recommends replacing the widget with [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/plaxo-widget?utm_source=plaxo&utm_medium=partner&utm_campaign=affiliate).  Unfortunately there does not appear to be a free option, but it sounds like you're probably willing to pay if you have to.